# Hiding <video> on iphone with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```
<video width="100%" height="100%" id="video" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="text-center">
    <ul class="list-inline controls">
        <li><a href="#" id="back"><img src="./css/images/back.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="pause"><img src="./css/images/play.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="stop"><img src="./css/images/stop.png"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="forward"><img src="./css/images/forward.png"></a></li>                                                          
    </ul>
</div>
$('#pause').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("video"); 

    if (myVideo.paused)
    { 
        $("#pause img").attr('src','./css/images/pause.png');
        myVideo.play(); 
    }
    else 
    {
       $("#pause img").attr('src','./css/images/play.png');         
       myVideo.pause(); 

    }
});
```

I want to show only the controls and keep the video hidden on mobile but hear the audio of the video.

It works perfectly on android devices, browsers, ipad, etc... my problem is with iphone.

i don't know why but i can't keep the video hidden on iphone, the video is hidden when the page is loaded but when i click the play button the video is showed on a black fullscreen so i guess that is something native to iphone.

any idea about how to fix this?

Comment: I'd suppose you could detect the iPhone with JS, and hide the video with like visibility: hidden;, or use absolute positioning and z-index to keep it behind other things and out of the way. It's a quite cheap trick though

Comment: Maybe Safari doesn't allow this. It's also not possible to autostart videos, probably to save battery. Alternatively add a pure Audio Element Fallback.

Comment: Seems what you are trying to achieve is not possible with iPhone. As far as I know, videos in iPhone Safari are played using the native video player. Therefore the solution gave by @LarsGraubner seems to me smart.